# Overflow error when creating pandas dataframe from dictionaries containing very large numeric values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Getting an error "OverflowError: long int too large to convert" when directly putting a table into pandas DataFrame. This seems to be due to the large numbers contained in the table, but there is no error trying on https://www.pythonanywhere.com/try-ipython/.  I've added a workaround to convert the values to float and THEN created the DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
table = [{'two': 2, 'one': 1}, {'two': 22, 'one': 11}, 
    {'two': 222, 'one': 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111}]

# workaround for overflow error
for x, i in enumerate(table):
    table[x]['one']=float(table[x]['one'])

df = pd.DataFrame(table)
```

Is there a better way to do this?  Others have pointed out that they do not get any overflow error.  This is python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, pandas tries to read and understand your data, and converts it to an appropriate datatype. In your case, it tried to load the data into `np.float64` objects. However, your data is obviously too large.

One workaround is to specify `dtype=object` when creating the dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(table, dtype='object')    
df
                                                 one  two
0                                                  1    2
1                                                 11   22
2  1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111...  222
```

Note that doing this kills all possibility of speed and efficiency, since `object`s are very slow to work with. I assume you are prepared for this, working with data of this nature.

Comment: Thanks!  Ideally we could specify dtype only on a specific columns, but appears to be an issue still https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/4464